# Log-space reduction from $USTCON$

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Is it possible to use $USTCON$ log-space decision algorithm in order to show reduction from $USTCON$ to some other decision problem $A$? I mean - the reduction will run $USTCON$ decision algorithm and then produce some output $x ∈ A$ or $x ∉ A$ accordingly?